# AWS some subdomain not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hello I am working on AWS Route 53 and EC2 I have 3 subdomains configured which were working by tomorrow perfectly. But today all of a sudden all the three stopped working after a while 1 one them started working but still the 2 of them are not working please suggest me what is the possible issue.

Comment: Please a dd more details to the question. What are the sub-domains pointing to ? What type of records are created? "Not Working" means, what is the error response you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily the records in Route53 that are broken. What types of records are not working? Where do they route? Does the location that they route to work?

If you for example pointed them to an Elastic Load Balancer that you deleted and recreated you will have to update the record in Route53 to point to the new load balancer.

Comment: I figure out that some time the pointing work on one network, but sometime not. So I suppose it is the problem of name servers associated with the primary domain. The problem arises only with the subdomans. Can you please tell me how to debug it because it is working automatically now. But I fear the problem wil be back in future.